# Android: removing and adding views to a recyclerView properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecyclerView that looks like a list, I'm setting each view a diffrent ID, and adding views by clicking on the first view, and removing views when they're clicked (expect the first one). What's not working correctly is when I remove a view and then add another one, the new view's ID breaks the order.

**The adapter**

```
public class AddEventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddEventsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

   private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(String name) {
        items.add(name);
        notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_event_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    static int i;

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView eventName;
        public RelativeLayout theLayout;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            eventName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
            theLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundevent);

            theLayout.setId(++i);
            eventName.setText(String.format("", i));

            theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == 1){
                    addItem("");
                }else {
                    removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }
}
```

**The implementation:**

```
    final AddEventsAdapter AddContainer = new AddEventsAdapter();
    AddEventsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    AddEventsRecycler.setAdapter(AddContainer);
    AddEventsRecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(666);

    AddContainer.addItem("");
```

**The layout for every row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/event_clicked_ripple"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundevent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/eventName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="something"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_shape"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is, if I add 5 views, remove the 2nd, and then add another one, it will add the 2nd again isntead of a 6th.
So I think the question here is how to not recycle the views after removing them?

Comment: What's wrong with just properly using `onBindViewHolder` as it is intended? Your view holder should *not* just set itself.

Comment: I'll use the onBindViewHolder to set each item's text, or are you saying there is something I should put into it that won't recycle the views after beeing removed?

Comment: I just see you setting text in the view holder upon creation `eventName.setText(String.format("", i));` This will obviously not get called again, thus leading to your problem. Bind your objects properly in `onBindViewHolder`, and if you need an id, add that id to your model, and not your viewholder

Comment: I placed this in the viewHolder `public void setEventNameName(String TheEventName){
            eventName.setText(TheEventName);
        }` 
and this on the onBindViewHolder `holder.setEventNameName(i + "");`
Still not working properly

Comment: You should not decide to delete based on the id of the view, if you're only deleting the views that are (not the first), then check based on the adapterPosition only, if the adapterPosition > 0, then delete() else add()

Comment: @aqm Ok I changed it, feels like a better practice

Comment: @Kurlicue -- I was thinking how about using a `ExpandableListView` instead. Will that fit into your requirement?

Comment: I'll be adding and removing items, isn't a recycler a better fit for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind RecyclerViews is that the view holder you provide in `onCreateViewHolder()` may be reused for views of the same `viewType`. This behavior is what makes RecyclerViews efficient - it is expensive to inflate views, and expensive to run `findViewById`.

You did not override `getItemViewType` so your RecyclerView only has one viewtype -- i.e. your ViewHolders are free to be recycled amongst each other as you scroll across many views, and delete/add views.

So what is happening in your code? When you delete view number two, its ViewHolder is recycled, and sent back to the recycler view pool. When you add view number 6, the recycler view uses the recycled view holder from number 2. Thus, `onCreateViewHolder` is never called (because there was an extra view to recycle!). However, `onBindViewHolder` *is* called. So add a method to update the data displayed by the ViewHolder:

```
 public void setData(final int position) {
    eventName.setText(String.format("", position));
    theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 1){
                addItem("");
            }else {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        }
}
```

and call this method in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     holder.setData(position);
}
```

Comment: I get the logic, it's still not working as intended tho. When I remove a view, the views after that change the ID to a number even superior to the number of views I've already added, feels weird.

Comment: Isn't there a way to not recycle the views after removing them?

Comment: The reason your number keeps increasing may be that you have `i` as a static int that you keep incrementing every time. You should set the number on the view to the position parameter you give to setData (that is passed through from `onBindViewHolder`())

Comment: If I do that, after deleting view 6, the view 7 will become view 6

Comment: In that case you should add a `position` field into a model object you create for your data. i.e. `items` would become a list of `Model`. Your model would contain the String currently in the ArrayList, as well as it's position. That way the rendered position would be set only once and is independent of the position of the item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `removeItem(int position)` to

```
public void removeItem(int position) {
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
}
```

It will most probably solve your issue

Comment: It's still messy, but diffrently, if I add 5 views and remove one, every view after the one I removed changes his ID to a random number

Comment: which layout your using for your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: RelativeLayout, I just added it to the question