# Android: customize a single row in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView behanving like a list, how do I change the background color of only one view? The item I want to change the color's ID is "1", I thought about getting it in the activity by it's ID and add it a decorator, but I don't know how to, or if it's even possible.

**Inside the adapter:**

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setEventNameName(i + "");
    holder.settheColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

}

static int i;
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView eventName;
    public RelativeLayout theLayout;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        eventName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.eventName);
        theLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.backgroundevent);

        theLayout.setId(++i);

        theLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getAdapterPosition()>0){
                    removeItem(getAdapterPosition());
                }else {
                    addItem("");
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void settheColor(int theColor){
        theLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(String.valueOf(theColor)));
    }

    public void setEventNameName(String TheEventName){
        eventName.setText(TheEventName);
    }

}
```

Comment: atleast put some code here.. so we can solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel you can do it in this way --

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    currentListItem = List.get(position);
    if(position == 0) //this will let you know the first child item
    {
       holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Think you can help me with another thing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666982/android-removing-and-adding-views-to-a-recyclerview-properly

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple, use the [onBindViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) method of your adapter, and change the color of the view (which should be referenced in your ViewHolder)

Follow this [example](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) if you are new to the Recyclerview concept.

Comment: I tried this but I'm not sure how to get the item's ID in the onBindViewHolder, can you provide an exemple please?

Comment: Hm, well, when onBindViewHolder is called, the position parameter allows you to know which data you are going to display. If you have a list which contains your items, just do a list.get(position) and handle the rest easily. If you provide some of your code, I'll be happy to give and example :)